# Properties of the prime geometric series

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

§1. The well known geometric sum is given by

```
g[x_] = Sum[x^n, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[659]= 1/(1 - x) *)
```

Here we consider the "prime geometric series" in which the exponents are restricted to primes.

This series can also be viewed as the generating function for PrimeQ[].

The partial sums are

```
gp[n_, x_] := Sum[x^Prime[k], {k, 1, n}]
```

We are interested in the limiting function

```
gp[x_] := Limit[gp[n, x], n -> \[Infinity]]
```

*Question 1*: what is known about this function?

§2. Let us start the study of some properties.

The quotient of the partial prime geometric sum and the usual (complete) geometric sum is

```
q[n_, x_] := gp[n, x] (1 - x)
```

The plot of the first various partial expressions is

```
Plot[Evaluate[Reverse[Table[q[n, x], {n, 1, 10, 3}]]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Reverse[{"1", "4", "7", "10"}], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Prime geometric series\nPartial sums divided by (complete) \
geometric series", AxesLabel -> {"x", "q"}]
```

[image]

This shows rapid convergence to the limiting function.

Some properties are

Series expansion

```
Series[q[20, x], {x, 0, 20}] // Normal

(* Out[733]= x^2 - x^4 + x^5 - x^6 + x^7 - x^8 + x^11 - x^12 + x^13 - x^14 + x^17 - x^18 + x^19 - x^20 *)
```

Maximum

```
(x /. FindRoot[D[q[20, x], x] == 0, {x, 0.6}])

(* Out[699]= 0.847929 *)
```

§3. Next consider the integral of the partial function

```
qi[n_] := Integrate[q[n, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

This can be written as a sum of terms

```
Integrate[(1 - x) x^Prime[k], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Prime[k] > 0]

(* Out[730]= 1/(2 + 3 Prime[k] + Prime[k]^2) *)
```

The integral of the limititng function is equal to the (obviously convergent) series

```
qic := Sum[1/(2 + 3 Prime[k] + Prime[k]^2), {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

Its approximate value is

```
Sum[1/(2 + 3 Prime[k] + Prime[k]^2), {k, 1, 20}]
% // N

(* Out[735]= 1298970839301699467/6674197770055015200 *)

(* Out[736]= 0.194626 *)
```

*Question 2*: is qic a known constant (and if so which one) or is it new?